# Apache returning blank page, only occasionally

Tags: apache, joomla

I am having a problem with Apache randomly returning a blank page.  It happens several times a day without any rhyme or reason. When this happens, the Apache access log indicates a 301 redirect to the same page which returns a 200 and no content, 0 bytes returned.  Reloading the page works normally returning a 200 with content.

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [05/Apr/2018:09:52:43 -0400] "GET /administrator HTTP/1.1" 301 255 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy Safari/537.36"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [05/Apr/2018:09:52:43 -0400] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy Safari/537.36"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [05/Apr/2018:09:52:47 -0400] "GET /administrator/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1937 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy Safari/537.36"
```

This is also a Joomla installation, but looking at the log I'm not sure how that would have any bearing. It also doesn't matter what page, it happens with random pages as well.

Comment: Is there any relevant info in the error_log?

Comment: There are no errors in the error log.  There are no PHP errors thrown.

Comment: maybe increase the verbosity of the log? or log directly in your index.php , you can log the timespec, the get/post/session arrays, and memory usage to get started